# Function not returning any values - Python

Tags: python

I wrote a menu function that loops until the user presses 3 to exit. But when the user asks for the other options by pressing 1 or 2 I want it to print something. Here is my code:

```
def Menu():
    return("\n"
          + "Menu:\n-------------"
          + "\n1 - Does This"
          + "\n2 - Does That"
          + "\n3 - Quit"
          + "\n")
    if option == 1:
        return "\nThis"
    if option == 2:
        return "\nThat"

option = None
while True:
    print(Menu())
    option = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    if option == 3:
        print("\nBye!")
        break
    if option < 1 or option > 3:
        print("\nIncorrect input!")
```

Instead of getting "This" when pressing 1 or "That" when pressing 2, it just loops the menu again until I press 3 to exit.

This is my current output:

```
Menu:
-------------
1 - Does This
2 - Does That
3 - Quit

Please choose an option: 1

Menu:
-------------
1 - Does This
2 - Does That
3 - Quit

Please choose an option: 2

Menu:
-------------
1 - Does This
2 - Does That
3 - Quit

Please choose an option: 3

Bye!
```

My desired outcome is just for it to print "This" or "That" then loop the menu again until I exit.

Comment: You never programmed that into the function

Comment: Just write it the way you wrote the exit part

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday and get flagged and deleted?

Comment: I remember you writing the gettysburg address to try to fill up space

Comment: Please explain this `return("\n" ...` and how you expect anything afterwards to be executed.

Comment: The first line in your function is a `return` statement. None of the lines after that will ever be read, so whatever code you write after `return` is ignored..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, when you choose either `1` or `2`, your while loop executes again. You need to implement the code where the user enter a valid value.

Just to clarify since you're returning in your `Menu()` function, those lines are never hit,

```
if option == 1:
    return "\nThis"
if option == 2:
    return "\nThat"
```

**EDIT**

Here is an improved and working version,

```
input_string = """Menu:-------------
1 - Does This"
2 - Does That"
3 - Quit
Please choose an option:"""

def Menu(option):
    if option == "1":
        return "\nThis"
    if option == "2":
        return "\nThat"

while True:
    option = input(input_string)
    if option in {"1","2"}:
        print(Menu(option))

    elif option == "3":
        print("\nBye!")
        break
    else:
        print("\nIncorrect input!")
```

Comment: *"You need to implement the code where the user enter a valid value"* ... I don't think that is of much help for a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually code a call to print the text. Give this a shot:

```
def Menu():
return("\n"
      + "Menu:\n-------------"
      + "\n1 - Does This"
      + "\n2 - Does That"
      + "\n3 - Quit"
      + "\n")


option = None
while True:
    print(Menu())
    option = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    if option == 3:
        print("\nBye!")
        break
    elif option == 1:
        print ("\nThis")
    elif option == 2:
        print ("\nThat")
    elif option < 1 or option > 3:
        print("\nIncorrect input!")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a little relocation

```
def Menu():
return("\n"
      + "Menu:\n-------------"
      + "\n1 - Does This"
      + "\n2 - Does That"
      + "\n3 - Quit"
      + "\n")


while True:
print(Menu())
option = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
if option == 1:
    print("\n Does This")
    continue
if option == 2:
    print("\n Does That ")
    continue
if option < 1 or option > 3:
    print("\nIncorrect input!")
    continue
if option == 3:
    print("\nBye!")
    break
```